# Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth' Error

Tags: .net, reactjs, angular, firebase, rxjs

I was learning the authentication in Angular through Firebase. I have used commands like `ng add @angular/fire` and `npm i @angular/fire` in order to install Firebase in my project. I have updated the `environment.ts` with the code snippet that I got on the console of Firebase. I have inserted some required Modules in `app.module.ts` Which is as follows:

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

//FireBase Setup
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';


//components and services.
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './Layouts/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './Layouts/footer/footer.component';
import { UserComponent } from './Components/user/user.component';
import { ReposComponent } from './Components/repos/repos.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './Pages/signin/signin.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './Pages/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './Pages/home/home.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './Pages/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    UserComponent,
    ReposComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`

I created one service named as `auth.service.ts` which is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private authA: AngularFireAuth) { }
  signIn(email:string, password:string){
    return this.authA.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }
}
```

I tried to remove `auth` from `return this.authA.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` but no luck.

The similar code is working on my friend's system, but not in mine.

My Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "github-login-firebase",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: You did ng add @angular/fire but I cannot see that's listed in dependencies object of your package.json

Comment: Tried with '"@angular/fire": "6.0.2",' in dependencies but issue is not resolved